# Does (new Date()).getFullYear() in Thailand return 2022 or 2056?

Tags: javascript, date, locale

Thailand uses a [different calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_calendar) and in Java date.format returns 2056. I have to make sure it matches my JavaScript code. What does this return in Thailand, 2022 or 2056?

```
(new Date()).getFullYear()
```

I know there's UTC time but my context is a bit limited.

Comment: Thai calendar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_calendar

Comment: It is the year `2565` this year in the Thai lunar calendar, not `2056`.

Comment: The [ECMAScript Date object](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-objects) uses the proleptic Gregorian calendar, that's it. The date and time represented by a Date instance can be converted to some other calendar using [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) or [*Date.prototype.toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) (which is effectively a shortcut to *Intl.DateTimeFormat*) with suitable options.

Answer (score 1):

In Thailand, there are 2 calendars; the normal **Gregorian** Calendar (solar-based) and the **Buddhist Calendar** (lunar-based) as called the **Thai lunar calendar**.

Javascript `Date()` will return the Gregorian Date. So, today is 11 March 2022.

If you use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` as specify the `Thai buddhist calendar`:

```
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US-u-ca-buddhist').format(new Date()));
```

it will return **"3/11/2565 BE"** which is the 11th day of Month 3 of the year 2565.

Note: This year is year **2565** in the **Thai lunar calendar**.

Comment: You can save a few keystrokes by using *toLocaleString* : `new Date().toLocaleString('en-u-ca-buddhist')` which returns something like "3/12/2565 BE, 11:54:11 AM". :-)

Comment: You are 100% correct. Sometimes too lazy with age :-)

Comment: How to get this format in TH?
สิงหาคม 7, 2566 เวลา 10:42